# Scala Future callbacks not seem to be doing anything

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I'm quite new to Scala and am playing around with Futures. I have this small piece of code which is is slightly different to a version I found in a tutorial.

```
object Tmp extends App {

  val f = Future {
    val r = Random.nextInt(500)
    if (r < 499)
      throw new RuntimeException("bad value")
    r
  }
  f.onComplete(ff => {
    if (ff.isSuccess) {
      println(s"success ${ff.get}")
    }
  })
  f.failed.foreach(t => s"failure ${t.getMessage}")
  // do the rest of your work
  println("A ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("B ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("C ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("D ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("E ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("F ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

Every time I run this, the output is:

```
A ...
B ...
C ...
D ...
E ...
F ...
```

I neither see the success / failure portions of the code execut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failure is thrown, but you ignore it with `if (ff.isSuccess)`. Here is how you should handle `onComplete`:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.util.Random
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


object Tmp extends App {

  val f = Future {
    val r = Random.nextInt(500)
    if (r < 499)
      throw new RuntimeException("bad value")
    r
  }

  f onComplete  {
    case Success(value) => value
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
  }

  // do the rest of your work
  println("A ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("B ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("C ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("D ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("E ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  println("F ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

your code throws an exception, because:

```
 if (r < 499)
  throw new RuntimeException("bad value")
```

The reason you don't see anything from the line

```
f.failed.foreach(t => s"failure ${t.getMessage}")
```

is because you only create the string, but don't do anything with it. Try this:

```
object Tmp extends App {

  val f = Future {
    val r = Random.nextInt(500)
    if (r < 499)
      throw new RuntimeException("bad value")
    r
 }
 f.onComplete(ff => {
   if (ff.isSuccess) {
     println(s"success ${ff.get}")
   }
   else{ //added this
     println(s"failes ${ff.get}")
   }
 })
 f.failed.foreach(t => println(s"failure ${t.getMessage}"))//and added this
 // do the rest of your work
 println("A ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
 println("B ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
 println("C ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
 println("D ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
 println("E ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
 println("F ..."); Thread.sleep(100)
 Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```